# Linking to Github in the register form thinks it's successful even when I close the access request popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

In Careers, if I click the Github linking button, and then simply close the access request popup, the icon changes its state from ready to successful even despite the Github authentication not being done:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Kindly have a look at this issue and find a better solution.

Comment: I've given your question a significant edit, and uploaded the images to our image hosting. Please give it a review and see if you're OK with its current state, and if it still communicates what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I have now fixed this. Previously we were marking the button as complete as soon as you came back to the window. Now we actually check to see if your account has been linked before turning the button green.